# Output from ffprobe and understanding where are the file differences?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

Just for learning purposes, who can answer this:

I have two video files, lets call it video1.mp4 and video2.mp4 (their size in bytes are exactly the same).

Upon doing file compare in Windows "fc video1.mp4 video2.mp4" the output shows differences.

Upon doing "ffprobe video1.mp4", and then "ffprobe video2.mp4, the output is exactly the same.

Does this mean that the 2 videos are REALLY the same, and what could be the differences as reported by file compare ?

--

Output from ffprobe, only the title is different obviously, but the rest is the same.

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'My scary movie.mkv':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: isomiso2avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : isom
    MINOR_VERSION   : 512
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.11.101
  Duration: 01:32:45.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6274 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.17.100 libx264
      DURATION        : 01:32:45.072000000
  Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.17.100 ac3
      DURATION        : 01:32:44.988000000
```